# How can the Starter Set's pre-made elf have 5 languages?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, languages, elf

So I'm not sure if I'm just missing something but the premade elf in lost mine of Phandelver should only have 4 languages (two from race and two from background) but for one reason it has 5. Can someone help me see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

While elves get Common and Elvish, high elves get an additional language of their choice.

> ***Extra Language.*** You can speak, read, and write one
>   extra language of your choice. (PHB p.24, "High Elf")

With two more languages of choice from their background this gives a high elf acolyte a total of 5: Common, Elvish, and 3 of their choosing. In the case of the elf from the Starter Set, those 3 are Draconic, Dwarvish, and Goblin.